# Can an array be used as a d3 nest key?

Tags: d3.js

I have a database of movies that I would like to nest by genre. The problem is that each movie can have multiple genres. So if I have several movies formatted like so

```
[
    {
        title  : 'foo',
        genres : ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Thriller']
    },{
        title  : 'bar',
        genres : ['Action']
    }
]
```

I'd like to nest them by each individual genre so that the result would be

```
[
   {
       key: 'Action',
       values: [ { title: 'foo' }, { title: 'bar'} ]

   },{
       key: 'Comedy',
       values: [ { title: 'foo' } ]

   },{
       key: 'Thriller',
       values: [ { title: 'foo' } ]

   }
]
```

Comment: Your result is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not directly, but you can expand your array

For example:

```
jj = [{ genre: ['thriller', 'comedy'], title: 'foo'}, { genre: ['thriller', 'action'], title: 'papa'}]
```

to expand your array:

```
jj2  = []
jj.forEach(function(movie) { movie.genre.forEach( function(single_genre) { jj2.push({ language: movie.language, genre: single_genre, title: movie.title } ); } ); })
```

Then you can perform your nesting as normal:

```
d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d.genre; }).entries(jj2)
```

Comment: That's what I though. This is how I was doing it anyway.